# How can AWS Copilot's manifest.image.context be set to the project repository's root directory?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-copilot, aws-copilot-cli

How can the AWS Copilot image.context manifest file parameter be set to the project’s root directory? I’m translating a Docker Compose file to Copilot manifest files but I’ve been unable to get Copilot to honor the image.context parameter using either relative or absolute paths.

**Approximate project repository structure:**

```
- project_root
  - src
    - api.py
  - copilot
    - api
      - manifest.yaml
  - requirements.txt
  - requirements
    - base.in
    - base.txt
    - development.in
    - development.txt
    - production.in
    - production.txt
  - dockerfiles
    - api
      - Dockerfile
      - start_agent.sh
      - start_api.sh
  - docker-compose.yaml
```

**Service Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.11
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements/ requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
COPY ./dockerfiles/services/api/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY --chmod=### ./dockerfiles/services/api/start_agent.sh /app/start_agent.sh
COPY --chmod=### ./dockerfiles/services/api/start_api.sh /app/start_api.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

**Service's Copilot manifest.yaml File**

```yaml
name: api
type: Backend Service
image:
  build: ./dockerfiles/services/api/Dockerfile
  context: .
  port: 8080
...
exec: true
network:
  connect: true
```

**Contexts Tried**

- "."
- "../.."
- "../../.."
- "/path/to/project/repo"

**Copilot Command Used**

```bash
# from project_root
copilot svc deploy --name api --env staging
```

For each image.context I get the same error that none of the file source locations of any of the Dockerfile COPY commands could be found. The only two workarounds I see are to restructure the project repository following the documentation examples or build the service images in docker, push to ECR, then use the imagee.location parameter instead.

**Copilot Error Message**

```
[+] Building 0.5s (14/14) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile  
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B
 => [internal] load .dockerignore
 => => transferring context: 2B
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11
 => [internal] load build context
 => => transferring context: 2B
 => [ 1/10] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11
  ...                                 
 => ERROR [10/10] COPY requirements.txt .
------
 > [10/10] COPY requirements.txt .:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found
```

In addition to the different contexts values tried, I've also upgraded copilot from version 1.25.0 to 1.29.1 using the homebrew aws/tap/copilot-cli tap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest file context parameter wasn't specified correctly. There are two ways to specify an image build process.

Option One

```
image:
    build: path/to/dockerfile
```

Option Two

```
image:
    build:
        dockerfile: path/to/dockerfile
        context: .
```

The second option accepts a context parameter. In the first option, context is assumed to be the same directory as the Dockerfile specified in the the [build parameter](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/rd-web-service/#image).